# How to fetch the attributes height, width, x and y from a column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

We have 1000 rows with the same information in a CSV file stored in one column as given below. How do we loop it and fetch attributes x, y, height and width in python?

```
[{"task":"T0","task_label":"Draw a box around each person name and transcribe their information.","value":[{"x":224.63333129882812,"y":89.96666717529297,"tool":0,"frame":0,"width":333.9999694824219,"height":42.00000762939453,"details":[{"value":"Rev. Leopold Wyke Acland"},{"value":0}],"tool_label":"Tool name"},{"x":95.63333129882812,"y":55.96666717529297,"tool":0,"frame":0,"width":280,"height":37,"details":[{"value":"Acland, Thomas Wyke"},{"value":0}],"tool_label":"Tool name"}]}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is this really all there is to your question? I'm not sure I understand your description of the CSV, could you share at least part of the file? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since the outermost `list` contains only a single object with namely 3 fields

1. `task` not required.
2. `task_label` not required.
3. `value` one we are interested in.

In the given context we can loop over the `dict` in following manner

```
for item in data[0]["value"]:
    print(f"x = {item['x']}")
    print(f"y = {item['y']}")
    print(f"width = {item['width']}")
    print(f"height = {item['height']}")
```

You can also collect those values in a more pythonic way and then iterate over the resulting list of dictionaries

```
result = [
            {
                "x": item["x"], 
                "y": item["y"], 
                "width": item["width"], 
                "height": item["height"]
             } 
          for item in data[0]["value"]]
```

I would suggest going through Iterations in python. Also, this snippet assumes that **all rows have uniform structure**.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 0):

If all rows are the same format you can iterate through the rows and capture the values in lists like so:

```
x, y, height, width = list(), list(), list(), list()

for row in rows:
    x.append(row[0]["value"][0]["x"])
    y.append(row[0]["value"][0]["y"])
    height.append(row[0]["value"][0]["height"])
    width.append(row[0]["value"][0]["width"])
```

You can store the captured values as a dict which is then easily converted to a pandas DataFrame:

```
d = {"x": x, "y": y, "height": height, "width": width}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the outer list truly only consists of 1 element, all of the content is in `l[0]['value']`:

```
In [14]: pd.DataFrame(l[0]['value']).iloc[:, :6]
Out[14]:
            x          y  tool  frame       width     height
0  224.633331  89.966667     0      0  333.999969  42.000008
1   95.633331  55.966667     0      0  280.000000  37.000000
```

If there are actually multiple entries, you can convert them one at a time and use `pd.concat`:

```
In [16]: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v['value']).iloc[:, :6] for v in l*3]).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[16]:
            x          y  tool  frame       width     height
0  224.633331  89.966667     0      0  333.999969  42.000008
1   95.633331  55.966667     0      0  280.000000  37.000000
2  224.633331  89.966667     0      0  333.999969  42.000008
3   95.633331  55.966667     0      0  280.000000  37.000000
4  224.633331  89.966667     0      0  333.999969  42.000008
5   95.633331  55.966667     0      0  280.000000  37.000000
```